# How to verify a bivariate density?

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, density-function

Verify that the following is a bivariate density:

$F(X, Y) = \displaystyle\frac{2}{\pi}$ for $X^2+Y^2\leq1$ and $X < Y$

$F(X,Y) = 0$ otherwise

Now, I know that verifying that this is a bivariate density involves taking a double integral and showing that it is equal to 1. However, I'm not quite sure what the limits are for this integral! Here is the integral I have:

$\displaystyle\int\displaystyle\int \displaystyle\frac{2}{\pi} dx dy$

How can I find out the limits for this integral?

Thank you!

Comment: Integrate over all possible values of $x$ and $y$ where $F(x,y)\neq 0$.

Comment: @MatthewGunn So, would that be $-1 \leq x < \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $-\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < y \leq 1$?

Comment: Close, but is $x=-1, y=-1$ possible? the range of one variable has to be conditional on the value of the other.

Comment: @MatthewGunn I'm not quite sure how to find that condition, though. I drew a picture of the area in question and see that $x=-1,y=-1$ is not possible, but how do I determine the conditional relationship?

Comment: If you draw a picture you can do this one by inspection.

Comment: Three approaches I would consider depending on how much time you want to spend. (1) Recognize that you're after $2/\pi$ times the area of the intersection of $x^2+y^2\leq1$ and $x<y$. What is that? (2) Recognize that this particular problem is invariant to rotation so you could use the algebraicly easier constraints $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ and $y \geq 0$ or (3) integrate over the region from $x \in (-1, 1/\sqrt{2})$ and $y$ what it needs to be (may be a good algebra/geometry/careful thinking exercise, but it's kinda of an unneccesary pain).

Comment: The limits are $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ :)

Answer (score 6):

My calculus is probably rusty.

I think it's a good idea to sketch the region over which you will integrate. Firstly, we know that:

$$X^{2}+Y^{2}\leq 1$$
which is the region bound by a unit circle. Furthermore, we have the constraint that:

$$X<Y$$
so the desired region is that bounded by a unit circle where $X$ is less than $Y$. To illustrate:

[image]

If you want you can convert to polar coordinates as follows:

$$\begin{align}
x=r\text{cos}(\theta)\\
y=r\text{sin}(\theta)
\end{align}$$
where the Jacobian is given by:

$$\begin{align}
J&=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\tfrac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \tfrac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\\
\tfrac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \tfrac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}
\end{array} \right|
\\
&=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\text{cos}(\theta) & -r\text{sin}(\theta)\\
\text{sin}(\theta) & r\text{cos}(\theta)
\end{array} \right|
\\
&=r
\end{align}$$

You'll be able to determine the appropriate limits of integration from the plot. In polar coordinates, the bounds are:

$$\begin{align}
0&\leq r\leq 1\\
\tfrac{\pi}{4}&\leq \theta \leq \tfrac{5\pi}{4}
\end{align}$$

The integral you want to evaluate is:

$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{\pi/4}^{5\pi/4}\int_{0}^{1}r\,dr\,d\theta$$

Comment: I've drawn the picture myself, I just can't figure out the correct limits for the integrals. How do I determine the relationship between $x$ limits and the $y$ limits?

Comment: @Bing In polar coordinates: $r$ is bounded by $0$ and $1$. $\theta$ is bounded below by $\pi/4$ and above by $5\pi/4$.